# When's this site going to be redesigned?

Tags: discussion, design

There are many Stack Exchange sites that look way better than this site, then why is this site still using the default Stack Exchange theme?

When will it be redesigned to look as awesome as others?

Comment: It will be redesigned when we graduate - which *could* be a few years... or maybe not. Nobody knows (precisely) when!